# Make a VStack fill the width of the screen in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Given this code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      Text("Title")
        .font(.title)

      Text("Content")
        .lineLimit(nil)
        .font(.body)

      Spacer()
    }
    .background(Color.red)
  }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
#endif
```

---

It results in this interface:

[image: preview]

How can I make the `VStack` fill the width of the screen even if the labels/text components don't need the full width?

---

A trick I've found is to insert an *empty* `HStack` in the structure like so:

```swift
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
  HStack {
    Spacer()
  }
  Text("Title")
    .font(.title)

  Text("Content")
    .lineLimit(nil)
    .font(.body)

  Spacer()
}
```

Which yields the desired design:

[image: desired output]

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 392, accepted):

Try using the `.frame` modifier with the following options:

```
.frame(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: .infinity,
      minHeight: 0,
      maxHeight: .infinity,
      alignment: .topLeading
    )
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      Text("Hello World")
        .font(.title)
      Text("Another")
        .font(.body)
      Spacer()
    }
    .frame(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: .infinity,
      minHeight: 0,
      maxHeight: .infinity,
      alignment: .topLeading
    )
    .background(Color.red)
  }
}
```

This is described as being a flexible frame ([see the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/204)), which will stretch to fill the whole screen, and when it has extra space it will center its contents inside of it.

Comment: The *subviews* don't align to left (`.leading`). Takes the full width if placed before `.background(Color.red)`

Comment: Added code to align to the left as well. Should match exactly now

Comment: This is wrong. The `.backgound(Color.red)` is the background of the frame's view, but not the background of the `VStack` that is in the frame view. (The reason for this is explained in the WWDC videos :P). If you put `.background(Color.green)` before the `.frame` you will see the `VStack` still has a width that fits its content while the frame has a red background...When you put `.frame(...)`, it's not editing the `VStack`, it's actually creating another view.

Comment: Have a question tho: Why to use alignment: .topLeading since we're having VStack(alignment: .leading) ?? Thanks for sharing

Comment: I've been debugging for a couple of hours now, pulling my hairs out, 'til I saw the frame options above. I know how to use that but never thought of trying that solution.

For context, my problem is that my custom rows/views hstacks with the typical layout icon + multi-line text are having inconsistent width.  Thanks for this reminder.

Comment: In fact `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)` is sufficient for most situations, if you are a minimalist.

Comment: `alignment: .topLeading` was the argument that I've been required. Kudos!

Answer (score 95):

With Swift 5.2 and iOS 13.4, according to your needs, you can use one of the following examples to align your `VStack` with top leading constraints and a full size frame.

Note that the code snippets below all result in the same display, but do not guarantee the effective frame of the `VStack` nor the number of `View` elements that might appear while debugging the view hierarchy.

---

### 1. Using `frame(minWidth:idealWidth:maxWidth:minHeight:idealHeight:maxHeight:alignment:)` method

The simplest approach is to set the frame of your `VStack` with maximum width and height and also pass the required alignment in [`frame(minWidth:idealWidth:maxWidth:minHeight:idealHeight:maxHeight:alignment:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3278571-frame):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Title")
                .font(.title)
            Text("Content")
                .font(.body)
        }
        .frame(
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            maxHeight: .infinity,
            alignment: .topLeading
        )
        .background(Color.red)
    }

}
```

---

### 2. Using `Spacer`s to force alignment

You can embed your `VStack` inside a full size `HStack` and use trailing and bottom `Spacer`s to force your `VStack` top leading alignment:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Title")
                    .font(.title)
                Text("Content")
                    .font(.body)

                Spacer() // VStack bottom spacer
            }

            Spacer() // HStack trailing spacer
        }
        .frame(
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            maxHeight: .infinity
        )
        .background(Color.red)
    }

}
```

---

### 3. Using a `ZStack` and a full size background `View`

This example shows how to embed your `VStack` inside a `ZStack` that has a top leading alignment. Note how the `Color` view is used to set maximum width and height:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Color.red
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Title")
                    .font(.title)
                Text("Content")
                    .font(.body)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

### 4. Using `GeometryReader`

`GeometryReader` has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader):

> A container view that defines its content as a function of its own size and coordinate space. [...] This view returns a flexible preferred size to its parent layout.

The code snippet below shows how to use `GeometryReader` to align your `VStack` with top leading constraints and a full size frame:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Title")
                    .font(.title)
                Text("Content")
                    .font(.body)
            }
            .frame(
                width: geometryProxy.size.width,
                height: geometryProxy.size.height,
                alignment: .topLeading
            )
        }
        .background(Color.red)
    }

}
```

---

### 5. Using `overlay(_:alignment:)` method

If you want to align your `VStack` with top leading constraints on top of an existing full size `View`, you can use [`overlay(_:alignment:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/3265521-overlay) method:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Color.red
            .frame(
                maxWidth: .infinity,
                maxHeight: .infinity
            )
            .overlay(
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Title")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("Content")
                        .font(.body)
                },
                alignment: .topLeading
            )
    }

}
```

---

Display:

[image]

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 68):

An alternative stacking arrangement which works and is perhaps a bit more intuitive is the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Hello World")
                    .font(.title)
                Text("Another")
                    .font(.body)
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }.background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

The content can also easily be re-positioned by removing the `Spacer()`'s if necessary.

[image: adding/removing Spacers to change position]

Comment: Good alternative Liked the gif

Comment: I find this both more intuitive and more aligned with OP's question, which I took to be about how to have the Stack element fill its container rather than how to interpose a container around the element.

Comment: I find this to be the best answer that is aligned with the idea behind SwiftUI

Comment: Definitively the most SwiftUI-y answer on here for such a common layout.

Answer (score 35):

There is a better way!

To make the `VStack` fill the width of it's parent you can use a `GeometryReader` and set the frame. (`.relativeWidth(1.0)` should work but apparently doesn't right now)

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Text("test")
            }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width,
                       height: nil,
                       alignment: .topLeading)
        }
    }
}
```

To make the `VStack` the width of the actual screen you can use `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` when setting the frame instead of using a `GeometryReader`, but I imagine you likely wanted the width of the parent view.

Also, this way has the added benefit of not adding spacing in your `VStack` which might happen (if you have spacing) if you added an `HStack` with a `Spacer()` as it's content to the `VStack`.

**UPDATE - THERE IS NOT A BETTER WAY!**

After checking out the accepted answer, I realized that the accepted answer doesn't actually work! It appears to work at first glance, but if you update the `VStack` to have a green background you'll notice the `VStack` is still the same width.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Hello World")
                    .font(.title)
                Text("Another")
                    .font(.body)
                Spacer()
                }
                .background(Color.green)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

This is because `.frame(...)` is actually adding another view to the view hierarchy and that view ends up filling the screen. However, the `VStack` still does not.

This issue also seems to be the same in my answer as well and can be checked using the same approach as above (putting different background colors before and after the `.frame(...)`. The only way that appears to actually widen the `VStack` is to use spacers:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack{
                Text("Title")
                    .font(.title)
                Spacer()
            }
            Text("Content")
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .font(.body)
            Spacer()
        }
            .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

Comment: Had tried `relativeWidth`, didn't work. Somehow `GeometryReader` works if `.frame` is placed before `.background(Color.red)`

Comment: I can't see `GeometryReader` in the list shown when I "Add Modifier" after I `Show SwiftUI Inspector`, or any where else within the UI.  How did you discover `GeometryReader`?

Comment: @gone - Stack Overflow :)

Comment: After testing the proposed solutions (also with iOS 15 beta), it turned out, the only way to accomplish a _correct_ solution is to use a GeometryReader. Partly, because filling the whole screen with `.infinity` values with the `frame` modifier is actually not always what you want at the end.

Answer (score 24):

EDIT: answer updated with simple (better) approach using .frame

Just use frame modifiers!

```
struct Expand: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Title")
                .font(.title)
            
            Text("Content")
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .font(.body)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity,maxHeight:.infinity,alignment:.topLeading)
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

note - you don't even need the spacer in the VStack!

note2 - if you don't want the white at top & bottom, then in the background use:

```
Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

[image]

Comment: this is not full screen.

Comment: the question didn't ask for full screen, it asked for full width. If you want to extend past the safe area, then use . edgesIgnoringSafeArea

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way I manage to solve the issue was is by using a ZStack + .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

```
struct TestView : View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

[image: Preview Image]

**Way Number 1 -> Using MaxWidth & MaxHeight**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.red)
    }
}

struct SomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SomeView()
    }
}
```

**Way Number 2 -> Using Main Screen Bounds**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        .background(.red)
    }
}

struct SomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SomeView()
    }
}
```

**Way Number 3 -> Using Geometry Reader**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryReader in
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: geometryReader.size.width, maxHeight: geometryReader.size.height)
            .background(.red)
        }
    }
}

struct SomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SomeView()
    }
}
```

**Way Number 4 -> Using Spacers**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
            HStack{
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(.red)
    }
}

struct SomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SomeView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

use this

```swift
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

Comment: Yeah! Thanks! That's Just It!

Answer (score 6):

A good solution and without "contraptions" is the forgotten `ZStack`

```
ZStack(alignment: .top){
    Color.red
    VStack{
        Text("Hello World").font(.title)
        Text("Another").font(.body)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by using `GeometryReader`

[GeometryReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader)

## Code:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
               Text("Turtle Rock").frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .topLeading).background(Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Your output like:**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One more alternative is to place one of the subviews inside of an `HStack` and place a `Spacer()` after it:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            HStack {
                Text("Title")
                    .font(.title)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                Spacer()
            }

            Text("Content")
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .font(.body)
                .background(Color.blue)

            Spacer()
            }

            .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

resulting in :

[image: HStack inside a VStack]

Comment: Imho, this is the most elegant solution

Answer (score 4):

This is a useful bit of code:

```
extension View {
    func expandable () -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Compare the results with and without the `.expandable()` modifier:

```
Text("hello")
    .background(Color.blue)
```

-

```
Text("hello")
    .expandable()
    .background(Color.blue)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me (`ScrollView` (optional) so more content can be added if needed, plus centered content):

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(Axis.Set.horizontal) {
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    ForEach(0..<8) { _ in
                        Text("")
                    }
                }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 50)
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Preview

#if DEBUG
struct SomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SomeView()
    }
}
#endif
```

> Result

[image: centered]

Answer (score 3):

I know this will not work for everyone, but I thought it interesting that just adding a Divider solves for this.

```
struct DividerTest: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Foo")
        Text("Bar")
        Divider()
    }.background(Color.red)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, using `Divider().hidden()` worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

## ⚠️ Important Note!

All other solutions are just adding a frame ***around*** the content!

✅ but this solution changes the **actual frame**!

---

## Simple and correct extension

You can use this modifier

```
.flexible(width: true, height: false)
```

---

### Demo

[image: Demo]

<sub>Note how contents are aligned exactly as you assign in the original stack</sub>

---

#### The code behind this ( [FlexibleViewModifier.swift](https://gist.github.com/MojtabaHs/836f752d5d04d4786eeb4452af6a9db5) )

```
extension View {
    func flexible(width: Bool, height: Bool) -> some View {
        self.modifier(MatchingParentModifier(width: width, height: height))
    }
}

struct MatchingParentModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var intrinsicSize: CGSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    private let intrinsicWidth:  Bool
    private let intrinsicHeight:  Bool

    init(width: Bool, height: Bool) {
        intrinsicWidth = !width
        intrinsicHeight = !height
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { _ in
            content.modifier(intrinsicSizeModifier(intrinsicSize: $intrinsicSize))
        }
        .frame(
            maxWidth: intrinsicWidth ? intrinsicSize.width : nil,
            maxHeight: intrinsicHeight ? intrinsicSize.height : nil
        )
    }
}

struct intrinsicSizeModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var intrinsicSize: CGSize

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.readIntrinsicContentSize(to: $intrinsicSize)
    }
}

struct IntrinsicContentSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGSize = .zero

    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

extension View {
    func readIntrinsicContentSize(to size: Binding<CGSize>) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader {
                Color.clear.preference(
                    key: IntrinsicContentSizePreferenceKey.self,
                    value: $0.size
                )
            }
        )
        .onPreferenceChange(IntrinsicContentSizePreferenceKey.self) {
            size.wrappedValue = $0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Login Page design using `SwiftUI`**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var email: String = "william@gmail.com"
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State static var labelTitle: String = ""


    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center){
            //Label
            Text("Login").font(.largeTitle).foregroundColor(.yellow).bold()
            //TextField
            TextField("Email", text: $email)
                .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(minHeight: 40)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(Color.green))

            TextField("Password", text: $password) //Placeholder
                .textContentType(.newPassword)
                .frame(minHeight: 40)
                .foregroundColor(.blue) // Text color
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(Color.green))

            //Button
            Button(action: {

            }) {
                HStack {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "Login")!)
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    Text("Login")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }


                .font(.headline)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("DarkGreen"), Color("LightGreen")]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                .cornerRadius(40)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)

                .frame(width: 200, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            }
            Spacer()

        }.padding(10)

            .frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, idealHeight: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            .background(Color.gray)

    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here another way which would save time in your projects:

***Much less code and reusable in compare to other answers which they are not reusable!***

---

```
extension View {
    
    var maxedOut: some View {
        
        return Color.clear
            .overlay(self, alignment: .center)

    }
    
    func maxedOut(color: Color = Color.clear, alignment: Alignment = Alignment.center) -> some View {
        
        return color
            .overlay(self, alignment: alignment)
        
    }
    
}
```

---

**use case:**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        Text("Hello, World!")
            .maxedOut
            .background(Color.blue)
        
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .maxedOut(color: Color.red)
  
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add `Color.clear` to the bottom of the `VStack`, simple as that :)

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
     VStack(alignment: .leading) {
       Text("Title")

       Color.clear
     }
     .background(Color.red)
   }
 }
```