# How do I get my UI to fit well on an iPad screen with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```swift
struct PasswordGenerator : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Upon clicking the button the password\nwill also be copied so you\ncan simply paste")
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: generatePassword) {
                    HStack {
                        Image("GeneratorGlyph")
                        Text("Generate!").font(.title)
                        }
                        .accentColor(.white)
                        .frame(minHeight: 56, maxHeight: 112)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 80)
                    }
                    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.init(red: 48/255, green: 153/255, blue: 216/255), Color.init(red: 65/255, green: 165/255, blue: 237/255)]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing), cornerRadius: 9)

                Spacer()
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Generator"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

This is how the code looks on the iPad Pro screen and I have no idea how to go about getting it to scale properly. Does anybody have any idea on how I could go about doing so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a VStack fill the width of the screen in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487323/make-a-vstack-fill-the-width-of-the-screen-in-swiftui)

Comment: What do you want the UI to look like?